# I am not able to passing the tabnames for tab Fragment

Tags: android

Parameters like this

```
adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB 1");
adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");`
```

working on Tab Fragment

Main Activity

```
    public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

        @Override
        protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
            super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
            setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        }
        private void setupViewPager(ViewPager viewPager) {
            SectionsPageAdapter adapter = new SectionsPageAdapter(getSupportFragmentManager());
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab1Fragment(), "TAB 1");
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab2Fragment(), "TAB2");
            adapter.addFragment(new Tab3Fragment(), "TAB3");
            viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);
        }
    }
```

Section page Adapter

```
class SectionsPageAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {

    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();
    private final List<String> mFragmentTitleList = new ArrayList<>();

    public void addFragment(Fragment fragment, String title) {
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
        mFragmentTitleList.add(title);
    }

    public SectionsPageAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public CharSequence getPageTitle(int position) {
        return mFragmentTitleList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
}
```

fragment tab1

```
 public class Tab1Fragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Tab1Fragment";

    private Button btntestBin1;

    @Nullable
    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.tab1_fragment,container,false);

        btntestBin1 = (Button) view.findViewById(R.id.btntestBin1);

        btntestBin1.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {

                Toast.makeText(getActivity(), "Testing Button click 1", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

        return view;


    }
}
```

I am trying to pass the addFragment() parameters but coming error like this,

> Change 1st parameter of method 'addFragment' from 'Fragment' to
>   'Tab1Fragment'

Comment: You are using `android.app.Fragment` use `android.support.v4.app.Fragment`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change this

```
 import android.app.Fragment;
```

to

```
import android.support.v4.app.Fragment;
```

in `Tab1Fragment`. Similarly check all your import. You need to use `Fragment` from support lib